# only do if day... batch file

Tags: batch-file, goto

hello i got a batch file, something like this:

```
if %day%==monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday (
goto yes
) else (
goto no
)
```

Now i know the first line won't work.

What i actually want to happen:

It automatticly checks which day it is. If it is Monday to Friday, it has to go to 'yes', otherwise (saturday/sunday) to 'no'.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran across this online.  Tested, and it works.  Returns the day as an integer, which you can still work with.

```
@For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
    Set Month=%%A
    Set Day=%%B
    Set Year=%%C
)

@echo DAY = %Day%
@echo Month = %Month%
@echo Year = %Year%
```

Comment: Note that this won't work on locales where the date separator is not /

Comment: This will not be a reliable solution, as when I use 'date /t' here, all I get is the short one (YYYY-MM-DD), thus no day name.  Goes with the locales.  If this is for exportation (anyone not being you), I wouldn't bet on this working as intended.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example bat file that will do this sort of thing I am sure you can think of other ways to use this sample code.  For instance anytime you need an "in" list.  The tricky bit is the %date:~0,3% this says expand the %date% environment variable and starting at position 0 the beginning of the string return the next 3 characters.  You can learn more about this from the "set /?" command.

example: **IsWeekDay.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%i in (Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri) do (
    if "%date:~0,3%"=="%%i" goto YES
)

:NO
echo No
goto EOF

:YES
echo Yes

:EOF
endlocal
```

Comment: +1 Excellent. It works on Window7 for me. @YourComputerHelpZ can you %date% from the command line and also date /t. Can you tell us what you get.

Answer (score 5):

As [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935858/only-do-if-day-batch-file/935944#935944) has mentioned, using `date /t` will only work on locales where this command outputs the day of week along with the date, and won't work on other locales (e.g. Russian). If you don't mind mixing your batch files with some VBScript, here's a solution that should work on all locales.

The trick is this tiny VBScript script that outputs the day of the week as a number (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ... 7 = Saturday):

```
WScript.Echo DatePart("w", Date)
```

You can run this script from your batch file, read its output and apply your logic:

```
for /f %%d in ('cscript dayofweek.vbs //nologo') do (
  if %%d==7 goto no   :: Saturday
  if %%d==1 goto no   :: Sunday
)
goto yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF %day% == monday GOTO YES
IF %day% == tuesday GOTO YES
IF %day% == wednesday GOTO YES
IF %day% == thursday GOTO YES
IF %day% == friday GOTO YES
GOTO NO
```

Comment: does it really do it by itself,, or have the user to type it in?

Comment: I assumed %day% was already set and he didn't fully understand branching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the batch fu to answer the question as asked, but, assuming this is a Windows batch file, consider executing the script using the task scheduler, which will let you set the kind of schedule you're asking for.

Comment: i understand you,, but then i also have to give a specific time. the BATCH file will just run at startup.

Comment: You can set a Trigger in Task Scheduler to execute "At startup" or "At log on". Doesn't have to have a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file that extracts day-of-week, day, month and year in an almost locale-neutral way.

The only locale specific thing is the spelling of the day-of-week, the rest is locale neutral.

So in English, it will return `Thu` for Thursday, but in Dutch that will be `do` (for donderdag).

```
:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi
:: Works on any NT/2k machine independent of regional date settings
::
:: 20110103 - adapted by jeroen@pluimers.com for Dutch locale
:: 20110303 - adapted by jeroen@pluimers.com for day-of-week
:: Dutch will get jj as year from echo:^|date, so the '%%c' trick does not work as it will fill 'jj', but we want 'yy'
:: luckily, all countries seem to have year at the end: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date
::            set '%%c'=%%k
::            set 'yy'=%%k
::
:: Also, in Dutch, there is a difference between %date% and date/t: the former will not include
:: the day-of-the-week, but the latter will.
:: That means the if "%date%A" LSS "A" trick does not work with %date%, we need a loop
:: to check if the day-of-the-week needs us to take tokens 2-4 in stead of 1-3:
::      if "%date%A" LSS "A" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
::      for /f "tokens=1" %%t in ('date/t') do (...)
::
:: Another difference between Dutch and English is that the Dutch date/t will prepend the day of the week in a lower case 2-letter form.
:: So the LSS "A" trick needs to be replaced with an LSS "a" trick
::      if "%date%A" LSS "A" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
::        if "%%ta" LSS "a" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
::
:: In addition, date will display the current date before the input prompt using dashes
:: in Dutch, but using slashes in English, so there will be two occurances of the outer loop in Dutch
:: and one occurence in English.
:: This skips the first iteration:
::        if "%%a" GEQ "A"
::
:: echo:^|date
:: Huidige datum: ma 03-01-2011
:: Voer de nieuwe datum in: (dd-mm-jj)
:: The current date is: Mon 01/03/2011
:: Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)
::
:: date/t
:: ma 03-01-2011
:: Mon 01/03/2011
::
:: The assumption in this batch-file is that echo:^|date will return the date format
:: using either mm and dd or dd and mm in the first two valid tokens on the second line, and the year as the last token.
::
:: The outer loop will get the right tokens, the inner loop assigns the variables depending on the tokens.
:: That will resolve the order of the tokens.
::
@ECHO off
    set v_day_of_week=
    set v_day=
    set v_month=
    set v_year=

    SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
      for /f "tokens=1" %%t in ('date/t') do (
        set v_day_of_week=%%t
        if "%%ta" LSS "a" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
      )
::DEBUG echo toks=%toks%
      for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('echo:^|date') do (
::DEBUG echo first token=%%a
        if "%%a" GEQ "A" (
          for /f "tokens=%toks% delims=.-/ " %%i in ('date/t') do (
            set '%%a'=%%i
            set '%%b'=%%j
            set 'yy'=%%k
          )
        )
      )
      if %'yy'% LSS 100 set 'yy'=20%'yy'%
      set Today=%'yy'%-%'mm'%-%'dd'%

    ENDLOCAL & SET day_of_week=%v_day_of_week% & SET v_year=%'yy'%& SET v_month=%'mm'%& SET v_day=%'dd'%

    ECHO Today is Year: [%V_Year%] Month: [%V_Month%] Day: [%V_Day%]
    set datestring=%V_Year%%V_Month%%V_Day%
    echo %datestring%
    echo day of week=%day_of_week%

    :EOF
```

Have fun with it!

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24999111/550712), we have

```
wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek
```

Expanding on this based on suggestions in [this thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3815), we can set a dayofweek variable as follows:

```
@echo off
REM Unset dayofweek in case set in a previous execution of this batch file
set dayofweek=
REM Get dayofweek into a variable.  Locale-specific:  0 is either Sunday or Monday.
for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') do if not defined dayofweek set dayofweek=%%a
echo %dayofweek%
```

Note that 0 can be Sunday or Monday depending your locale.